# Can't set few numbers into <input type="number">

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am trying to set few numbers into `<input type="number">` like 22,33,44, but after submited my form, the value into my input tag is "", if I set only two numbers it works like "22.33", but with 3 numbers validation is not pass. How can I set 3 numbers or more and pass the validation?

Comment: `type="number"` means you can only enter **one** actual number

Comment: How can i set few numbers into input? And it's still need to be numeric input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<input type="text" pattern="(\d+)(,\s*\d+)*" />` instead.

Comment: Could work, but remember that `^` and `$` are implicit in the pattern

Comment: Oh, yes. I will change that.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is the commas ',' you have. Input type 'number' only takes in numbers, it is invalid with commas, remove comma and it should work

Comment: If I remove comma it will be only one number, isn't it?

Comment: yes you should go with approach that take input type 'text' and parse the numbers. but i would just go with multiple inputs for better usability

Answer (score 0):

Into `<input type="number">` you can inser only a number, "22.33" is still a signle number, but it's decimal, not an intere which is correct.

If you want to insert multiple numbers separated by comma (,) you have to use `<input type="text">` and then parse the content of the input.

Comment: Yeah, It would be great idea, but I can't use "text" type, its conditions for this input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use type text and perform the validations using regex or string manipulation.
input type = number is used to set only single value like 22 or 33 or 44 but not combination i.e. "22,33,44".

Comment: So it's the only way to use "text" type? Unfortunately I can't use this type, its conditions for this input.

Comment: no it's not possible you need to change the type to text and perform validations either using pattern (guess not supported in IE9), else JS function validation like doing string. manipulation